# What is the c++ equivalent of this class definition

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to learn C++ but my first language in Python. I am struggling a bit to understand the constructor in C++, and more specifically the variable size arrays and strings. Could someone write the C++ equivalent of the following class definition so I can follow the logic?

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, color, flavor, poisonous):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.flavor = flavor
        self.poisonous = poisonous
```

Comment: There is no C++ code that could be equivalent to that.

Comment: In C++ we use "this" instead of "self" and you don't have to include that in the constructor parameters, "this" is always there by default (unless its a static method). Also, there is no need to refer to your class properties as `this.property = value`, simply `property = value` will do, and for that reason your constructor function shouldn't use parameters with the same name as the class properties.

Comment: `this.property` would go horribly wrong, because `this` is a *pointer*, if you need to use `this`, use `this->property`instead... (however, as @Havenard pointed out, it is not needed here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```cpp
class Fruit {
    std::string name;
    std::tuple<uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t> color; // for RGB colors
    std::string flavor; // Assuming flavor is a string
    bool poisonous;

    Fruit(const std::string& nm, const std::tuple<uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t>& clr, const std::string& flvr, const bool psns) : name(nm), color(clr), flavor(flvr), poisonous(psns) {}
}
```

The `__init__` function does something very similar to a constructor in C++. Because in C++, you need to specify variable types, I took some liberty in assuming that `name` and `flavor` are strings, `color` is a 3-tuple of values from 0 to 255 (RGB) and `poisonous` is a boolean (`bool`) value.

Comment: I have come across some methods using pointers `new` and `delete`, could you write that version? I think that would be easier in this phase for me

Comment: `new` and `delete` are ugly, because they require you to take care of using `delete` on all the pointers created with `new`. This just copies the values given to the constructor to the class attributes and is (IMHO) probably easier to use for beginners. If you are wondering about the `: name(nm), ` etc. part, check out e.g. [this tutorial on initialisation lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).

Comment: `new` and `delete` don't apply to this example. You use those when you are creating objects that are not supposed to be deleted automatically when they lose inheritage. If you create your class properties with `new`, you will have to write a destructor to dispose of them later with `delete` once your object is deleted too. The way it is, all that will happen automatically.

Comment: what if I want to use `char` for `name` and `flavor`

Comment: Why go back to C stuff when you have C++? `std::string` will take care of all the boring part for you. Forget buffer handling, focus on keeping your code clean and readable.

Comment: Then you have `const char*` or `char*` as type for the arguments. If you are fine with not copying the content, keep it similar to what it is now, otherwise, you will have to allocate memory and use `strcpy`. My advice for that: **don't**. If you have a `char*` or `const char*`, pass it into `std::string(whatever)` to make a proper C++ string.

Comment: @Havenard indeed, but the textbook used the `char` so far for strings, its a bit hard to grasp all these stuff at once. I have no idea what `std::string` does :(

Comment: `std::string` is basically a `char*` buffer on steroids. In fact you can get the `char*` from it with `name.c_str()`. It will resize automatically, append new text with  `+` instead of `strcat()`, compare to other strings with `==` instead of `strcmp()` etc. Forget buffer overflows and boring memory management. It will feel very much like the stuff you can do with strings in Python.

Comment: @WolfgangKuehne `std::string` is a bit like a python `str` that you can modify.

Comment: why do we use `const std::string& nm` in the constructor and not just `std::string nm`? the usage of `&` and `const` confuse me. For what purpose are they useful?

Comment: `&` means you pass a reference to the constructor. That means that the contents of the string are not copied twice (into the constructor, and then into `name`), but only once (into `name`). Also, `const` means that the contents of `nm` (or rather of what is referenced by `nm`) **will not be changed** by the constructor (this does *not* mean that `name` is also constant)

Comment: how would a __str__ method look like in c++ ? I mean its equivalent, so that when you write "cout << myObj" it displays the attributes of the object neatly...?